# Laravel Loading Service Provider and Alias

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Maybe it is just me but im not sure what this do and why they need to do this?

in the providers that are loaded in laravel they did this

```html
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,

...
```

same for alias

```html
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,

...
```

What does the ::class do and why can't they just leave it off like this?

```html
'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just return class name with namespace !

Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution.
You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class.
 This is particularly useful with namespaced classes.

```
namespace NS {
    class ClassName {
    }
    echo ClassName::class;
}
```

**The above example will output:**

```
NS\ClassName
```

[Source 1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-what-is-class?page=1)

[Php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)